# Why is Android countdown timer running past zero

Tags: java, android

I have a countdown timer that begins counting down the hours, minutes, and seconds between the current date and time and a future date and time.

The problem is that I've encountered a behavior from my countdown timer where it continues running past 00:00:00. The countdown timer works fine besides that, but I'm just not sure why it continues on to 00:00:-1, 00:00:-2, 00:00:-3...

I added an if condition that cancels the timer once the time is equivalent to "00:00:00", which did the trick, but I still want to know why I'm experiencing this issue. I'm pretty sure this isn't normal because I've seen countdown timer tutorials that stop once it hits 0 without having to add additional logic. Is there something I've missed?

```
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setLenient(false);

    String endTime = "23.12.2018, 01:35:00";
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;
    long endTimeMilli = 0;

    try {
        endDate = formatter.parse(endTime);
        endTimeMilli = endDate.getTime();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    startDate = new Date();
    startTime = startDate.getTime();

    if(startTime >= endTimeMilli)
        return;

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(endTimeMilli, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            startTime -= 1;
            long serverUptimeSeconds =
                    (millisUntilFinished - startTime) / 1000;

            int hoursLeft = (int) serverUptimeSeconds / 3600;
            int minutesLeft = (int) serverUptimeSeconds  % 3600 / 60;
            int secondsLeft = (int) serverUptimeSeconds % 3600 % 60;

            String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hoursLeft, minutesLeft, secondsLeft);
            mCountdown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);

            if(mCountdown.getText().toString().equals("00:00:00"))
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() { }
    }.start();
```

Comment: you get a `long` type `serverUptimeSeconds `, and then you cast it into int by  `(int) serverUptimeSeconds / 3600;`. this may result in negative int value. Do you know that casting has a higher priority than the divison and the mod operation?

Comment: try this: `int secondsLeft = (int) (serverUptimeSeconds % 3600 % 60);` and tell me if it works

Comment: @ZhaoGang I'm sure I learned that in school but I must have forgotten, so thank you for the reminder! I enclosed the division and mod operations with parentheses but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Have you figured it out? I researched this issue and suggest that: `long serverUptimeSeconds =
                    millisUntilFinished  / 1000;`

Comment: @ZhaoGang sorry I'm just getting back to you. Been with family for the holidays, but I just tried your suggestion and it didn't solve my problem. I'm just going to leave it alone and continue working on the rest of the project since its just a minor issue. I appreciate you looking into it!